# The "rtf" file extension is disappearing during the execution of the mime/extension validation script using "finfo" PHP class

Tags: php, upload, mime, rtf

I am trying to create a cross validation of uploaded files through phpmailer using the `"extension X mime"` file values, the system is working to almost all files that i need to do this, but exceptionally with `.rtf` files the script isn't working.

The extension just disappear, the script can't get this if the file is `.rtf`. I'm using this script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349901/4623271 with some adaptations.

Bellow in the code, is the variable `$ext` where i can get the extension of any files allowed by the verification, except `.rtf` files, when the file is a `.rtf`, the variable becomes apparently empty.

I tried using `$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]));` but in the same way, when is a `.rtf` file, the variable becomes empty.

```
    // mime verification
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'doc' => 'application/msword',
            'docx'  => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            'rtf' => 'application/msword',
            'odt' => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
            'txt' => 'text/plain',
            'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
        ),
        true
    )) {
         $errorMsg .= "<br> Please, watch that the formats allowed are: \"doc\", \"docx\", \"rtf\", \"odt\", \"txt\", \"pdf\"' ";
    }
```

For the time you spent reading this, thank you.

Comment: Is this on apache? what is your .htaccess look like? also it could be because php cannot parse .rtf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678192/is-it-possible-to-display-an-rtf-file-inside-a-web-page-using-php

Comment: thank you for the answer, i read the page, but i'm not looking to parse the file content, i just want to get the extension of the .rtf file and put this in the variable as it has worked with the other file types.

Comment: is this on apache? do you have a .htaccess file?

Comment: No, this is not in Apache, it's windows server

Comment: Windows Server is a platform and doesn't know what PHP is. Do you perhaps mean that you are using IIS which is the MS flavor of web server?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the problem is in mime value that i was using in array to validate the `.rtf` file.

The mime type readed by `$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);` is not the usual mime type finded in online tables with this kind of information and that i have used to create the initial array.

After searching for help in a Brazilian PHP Telegram group, I received the hint to analyse the value of the `$finfo` variable.

When i applied `var_dump ($finfo->file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name']));` I discovered that to `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` the mime of `.rtf` files is: `text/rtf` and not `application/rtf`, that as i said above, is the most common option of mime type to `.rtf` files.

Because of this, the validation error was occurring since the script expected `text/rtf` to associate with `.rtf`file.

After I change the key value for `text/rtf` instead `application/msword`or `application/rtf` , the script worked as expected.

Now i´m sending attachments with mime validation using phpmailer.

Thanks to all who tried to help in some way.